# How to rectify oci8.c error when executing a rest ruby script on DB application?

Tags: ruby, oracle, rubygems, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I'm executing ruby scripts for a REST based application which uses oic8 gems from ruby. While executing I end up with following error 
I'm executing in linux box

```
OCIError:
    ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
  # oci8.c:694:in oci8lib_210.so
  # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.2/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:147:in `initialize'
  # ./lib/common/oracle_connection.rb:9:in `new'
  # ./lib/common/oracle_connection.rb:9:in `initialize'

oci8.c:694:in oci8lib_210.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.2/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:147:in `initialize'
./lib/common/oracle_connection.rb:9:in `new'
./lib/common/oracle_connection.rb:9:in `initialize'

692# Couldn't get snippet for oci8.c
```

Please let me know what is that I'm missing here. I have installed oracle and set oracle home path and also installed ruby oci Gem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you (the person running ruby) have correct file permissions on the Oracle directory (or directories) so you can see files.  Use `chmod 755` as needed.

Comment: I'm logged in and running as root.

Comment: You really need to give more detail about the install.  What Oracle software, what environment variables, whether your app resets the environment when it starts (like Apache would), etc. etc.  Please update your question with the information.